# c++ class collision across dll

Tags: c++, dll, rtti

I have a base abstract class (`interface`) which is shared across many DLLs to inherit from it. Each DLL has an exported factory symbol which dynamically creates an object and returns its pointer. What will happen if two different DLLs have classes with same name inherited from same abstract class?

```
class foo
{
public:
  virtual void func()const=0;
};
```

Dll1

```
class bar: public foo
{
public:
  virtual void func()const{
    std::cout << "From Dll1" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Dll2

```
class bar: public foo
{
public:
  virtual void func()const{
    std::cout << "From Dll2" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Main

```
int main()
{
  foo* obj1;
  foo* obj2;
  // load DLLs
  // import factory
  // call factory to initialize objects
  obj1->func(); // output: "From Dll1"
  obj2->func(); // output: "From Dll2"
  return typeid(*obj1) == typeid(*obj2);
}
```

Returns `true` meaning `obj1` and `obj2` are both instantiated from the same class. As well as `typeid(*obj1).name()` and `typeid(*obj2).name()` returns the same name `class bar`. Is there any way I can distinguish those objects using `RTTI` if I am not allowed to control DLLs themselves? Does class have to have a mechanism to provide its `UUID` for this case?

**P.S.**
As [IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) has said you can map object to its factory. But what if interface allows to compund objects? DLL would never distinguish between objects returned from different modules since it is unaware about factory. That's the main reason I would like to use `RTTI`.

Comment: When you say *"import factory"* you already have to provide the module that implements it, one way or another. If you don't feel like storing the mapping between function pointers and modules, you can retrieve the module from the function pointer at any time, by calling [GetModuleHandleEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for your reply! I would like to be able to compound objects from across modules. There could be some constrains in derived class implementation to accept only objects of certain kind.

Comment: Spreading CRT resources across module boundaries is synonymous for entering a world of pain. It's something you *can* get right, but it requires intimate knowledge of the intricacies and dire diligence. See [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx) for details. While all of this looks like you're re-inventing COM, why not use the Real Thing™ instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this kind of construct only possible with [run time dynamically linking of your DLLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810279.aspx).  If you would use [load-time dynamic linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the linke would identify the duplicate symbols in the import library.  So we are no longer in the standard C++ but in implementation specific behavior:

```
HINSTANCE dll1Handle = LoadLibraryA("Test0410-1DLL1.dll");
HINSTANCE dll2Handle = LoadLibraryA("Test0410-1DLL2.dll");
fct f1, f2;
foo *obj1, *obj2; 

if (dll1Handle == NULL || dll2Handle == NULL) {
    cout << "Both DLL couldn't be uploaded!" << endl; 
}
else {
    f1 = (fct)GetProcAddress(dll1Handle, "myfactory");
    f2 = (fct)GetProcAddress(dll2Handle, "myfactory");

    if (f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL) {
        cout << "Both factories couldn't be uploaded!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        obj1 = f1(); 
        obj2 = f2(); 

        obj1->func(); 
        obj2->func();

        if (typeid(obj1) == typeid(obj2))
            cout << "Same type"<<endl; 
        else cout << "Different type" << endl; 
    }
}
```

The code generated by MSVC finds out that both have the same type.  But nothing ensures this behavior.

It's also difficult to use the pointers of the virtual function, because, you can't take the address of `obj->func`,  you need to [take the address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/850cstw1.aspx) of `foo::func` which is a relative address and will be the same for both classes.

As your construct is at the limit of the [ODR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) and builds on implementation specific behaviour, I think that the easiest way to safely distinguish your classes, would be to provide a home-made virtual type identification function in `foo` which would for example combine the class and the dll name.